# Adding data to chart

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a dynamic chart taking in a number of series depending on the amount that I have loaded into the workbook. I load the data into one sheet called Data, and I plot the chart in one sheet called Plots. I tried recording a macro to get a better understanding as to how to do this, and ended up with something like this. My problem is that I would like "=Data!$A$15" etc to be a cell.value so that I can use "i" to determine the number of series needed. How do I do this elegantly (like the below sheet).

```
Do Until i = LotAmount
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = "=Data!$A$15"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).XValues = "=Data!$B$7:$F$7"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Values = "=Data!$B$15:$F$15"
i = i + 1
Loop
```

I hope you can help me :)

Best Regards

Lonnie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is the delvat value between your row number and `i`, but you could use something like the code below:

```
With ActiveChart
    Do Until i = LotAmount
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(i).Name = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & i)
        .SeriesCollection(i).XValues = Sheets("Data").Range("B7:F7")
        .SeriesCollection(i).Values = Sheets("Data").Range("B" & i & ":F" & i)
        i = i + 1
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed :)